# C# Sendkeys in Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista, 32-bit, sendkeys, incompatibility

I was working on a macro program in C#, which used SendKeys.Send(Wait) and worked fine in Windows XP.

Most people know that using sendkeys in Vista (32-bit) or above causes problems, but mine seems a little strange:

When using: SendKeys.Send("B");
- It doesn't do anything.

When using SendKeys.SendWait("B");
- It sends about 10 B's before it stops.

Does anyone know what to do now, because this doesn't leave alot of other options.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of .Net are you using? See the note about using SendKeys in Vista at [SendKeys Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

You can also try using [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) as an alternative. It has much more powerful api too.

Comment: Aah, that's exactly what I need! I'll test it as soon as possible, and then I'll let you know how it worked out. Thanks again!